# How can I add entries in the project's info.plist when user installs my pod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

How can I add entries in the project's `info.plist` when user installs my **pod**. Is there a way to do this or the user will have to do it manually?

Answer (score -1):

To add entries to a project's `Info.plist` file when a user installs your CocoaPod, you can use a post-install hook in your podspec file. The post-install hook allows you to run custom scripts or commands after the pod is installed.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

1. Open your podspec file (usually named `YourPodName.podspec`).
2. Add a `post_install` block to the podspec. Inside this block, you can use the `installer` object to access the target and modify its `build_configurations`.

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  # ... other podspec configurations ...

  spec.post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      # Check if the target is the main target of your pod
      if target.name == 'YourPodMainTarget'
        # Access the build configurations
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          # Access the Info.plist file path
          plist_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path

          # Use a PlistBuddy command to add entries to the Info.plist
          system("/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :YourKey string YourValue' #{plist_path}")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In this example:

- Replace `'YourPodMainTarget'` with the actual name of the main target of your pod.
- Replace `'YourKey'` and `'YourValue'` with the key-value pair you want to add to the `Info.plist` file.

The `system` command is using the `PlistBuddy` tool, which is a command-line tool for interacting with Info.plist files. Make sure to adjust the key and value according to your requirements.

After making these changes, users will see the specified entries in their project's `Info.plist` file when they install your pod.